# Move entire contents of cell based on whether it contains a specific character-Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I want to create a macro in Excel 2007 to search Column A for a colon (:) and if found, move the entire cell value into the same row Column B. Thus it my data looks like this:

```
Column A     Column B
1:256   
13.049 
1:200    
1:100   
1:200   
1:512   
> 1:512 
13.909
1:100   
1:512   
1:512   
16.610
```

And to look like this post running macro:

```
Column A    Column B
            1:256   
13.049 
            1:200     
            1:100   
            1:200      
            1:512   
            > 1:512 
13.909
            1:100   
            1:512        
            1:512   
16.610
```

Ideas anyone?

Comment: What's stopping you from creating this macro?  Specifically which part are you not sure about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always good to show your work here ..

try to show your work hereafter but i help you this time

TESTED - Working fine

```
Sub tested()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lrow As Integer

With ActiveSheet
lrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng In .Range("A2:A" & lrow)

If InStr(rng.Value, ":") > 0 Then

rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Value
rng.Value = ""
End If

Next rng

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am new to excel coding and didn't know where to look - cut and paste excel macro - did not show me the below page. After reviewing your code and doing a google search on ActiveSheet.Range I found the following web page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308/en-us which helped me understand your code and gave me some additional pointers for future coding.

Comment: Glad to help :) Never give up .